# How to invest in stock market for a Canadian expat (non tax-resident of Canada)?

Tags: stocks, canada, investing

I am a Canadian citizen but non tax-resident of Canada. I am currently working in China and paying my taxes there. I previously had an investment account with BMO Investor Line in Canada but they do not want to let me buy stocks anymore since I am not a tax resident of Canada anymore.

I am looking for other countries where I could open an investment account to buy stocks. However, I found it difficult to open a stock market account in other countries. In mainland China, I cannot open the stock market account. In Hong Kong, I cannot open the stock market account as they do not allow Canadians to have a stock market account there due to tax regulations.

In which countries would a non-tax resident Canadian could open an investment account, and where it would be advantageous?

Ideally, I would prefer to not pay tax in Canada (to avoid filling an income tax report) but in China or in another country.

Singapore? Other countries?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to invest in any stock market, (potentially) anywhere in the world? Or do you want to invest specifically in Canadian stocks?

Comment: Any stock markets would be fine. I just don't want to buy a "time deposit" and get 1 % interest. So I am looking to invest in some stock markets. And of course a larger stock market would be better. If I would invest in the Canadian stock market, I am afraid that it would make it more complicated for taxes (would I lose the non-tax resident status?) So I am thinking that it is maybe better that I avoid the canadian stock market.

Answer (score 1):

You could register a company in Hong Kong and have the company open a traders account as a local entity.

Comment: Probably not in a day, but there are companies that specialize in this sort of thing.